# Bootstrap not displaying correctly in Chrome Android and Win8.1 (OK in Chrome iOS app, Safari and IE11)

Tags: javascript, android, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Bootstrap Buttons and Grid layout of iframe elements are not working in Chrome in Android phone and Win 8.1 PC. The page displays well in Chrome and Safari in iOS(iPad), and Win8.1 IE11.

Buttons are defined as:

```
<a href="http://weather.gc.ca/trends_table/pages/yvr_metric_e.html" class="btn btn-info" role="button" target="_blank">YVR 24hrs</a>
```

A 3 across grid of iframes, are defined as:

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <iframe width="210" height="210" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kTIy2JRSkkUoubdQ_pPMpSfXSCoG-U16Q1gjUpS_Eok/pubchart?oid=879890587&amp;format=interactive"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <iframe width="210" height="210" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kTIy2JRSkkUoubdQ_pPMpSfXSCoG-U16Q1gjUpS_Eok/pubchart?oid=1692765152&amp;format=interactive"></iframe>
                </div>
```

[Bootstrap elements display correctly in Chrome iPad (image), as well as in IE in Win8.1.
**Problem:** Buttons are simplified as text links and iframes stacked in Chrome Android phone Portrait and Chrome Android phone Landscape, and Chrome Win8.1 desktop. CLICK for Images](https://557f656911259c9bcef133b1b08b60a176416b13.googledrive.com/host/0Bzk9LjKn9VCYQU15cUZWME5nV1k/)

Comment: _Buttons are simplified as text links_ - That sounds like the CSS isn't getting loaded for some reason. Have you checked that in the Chrome browser?

Comment: Thanks @BSMP,Firebug is showing the basic style.css, but not the bootstrap